# how to print out a table in nextflow

Tags: nextflow

I am starting out with Nextflow and can't seem to figure out why my script isn't doing what I'm expecting

```
import nextflow.Channel

params.groupings = "SampleGroups.csv"
params.comparisons = "comparisons.tsv" 

groupings = params.groupings
comp = params.comparisons

println groupings.class

def parseGroupings(groupings){
def allRows = [:]

Channel.from(groupings)
    .splitCsv(sep: ',', header: true)
        .unique().map { row ->
   [row.Sample,row.Group]
}


}


(a,b) = parseGroupings(groupings).into(2)
println a.flatten().unique().toSortedList().get()
```

I am expecting it to print the rows of the groupings file I put in but instead I get:

```
class java.lang.String
[]
```

The array is empty, but my file is clearly not. What's the easiest way to check the contents of my output and "see" what I'm doing?

Answer (score 2):

Use `.view()` to inspect a channel's content and return a copy of that channel.

```
Channel.from(1,2,3).view()
        .map { it -> [it, it+it, it*it] }
        .view()
        .set { foo }
foo.collect().view()
```

output:

```
1
2
3
[1, 2, 1]
[2, 4, 4]
[3, 6, 9]
[1, 2, 1, 2, 4, 4, 3, 6, 9]
```

Comment: thank you! in part thanks to you, I was able to figure out that I had not properly read in the file. instead I was running splitcsv on the string params.groupings. I changed one line to "groupings = file(params.groupings, checkIfExists: true)" and was on my merry way. now I have several outputs of view that don't say java.lang.String or whatever in my output, because I added them in like 10 different places. excellent!